# Starting qsub in parent folder with Python fails

Tags: python, pbs

I'm creating a Python script to setup a series of calculations on a remote calculation cluster. However I have run into a problem.

The calculation on the remote server is started with the command:

```
qsub Run.sh
```

Run.sh is located in the folder ./sol/

If I enter ./sol/ and run:

```
python25 -c "import os;os.system(\"qsub Run.sh\")"
```

Every thing works like it should.
However, If I am located in ./ and run this command:

```
python25 -c "import os;os.chdir(\"sol\");os.system(\"qsub Run.sh\")"
```

qsub failes with this error message:

```
*** error from copy
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
*** end error output
```

Does anyone know why this is? I use python version 2.5.1 and unix 2.6.18

Comment: What happens if you just do `qsub ./sol/Run.sh`? I have a feeling `Run.sh` is executing from the top level directory instead of the `./sol` directory. PBS is picky about what directory the job actually starts in sometimes.

Comment: It fails with the same error. Do you know if there is a workaround?

Comment: Have your `Run.sh` change into the directory it's supposed to run from, ie. `cd /path/to/sol/` before it does anything else to make sure it's in the right spot.